# Run IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation on IBM Containers

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am following the MobileFirst containers tutorial: 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

I have already created mobilefirst project. Now I want to use that project war file. As per above link, all installation process is done. Now I am facing an issue while running the scripts. When I try to run `prepareserverdbs.sh` it asks me to specify the name of my Bluemix application (mandatory). Which name should I provide there?

I tried with same war file name which I created but its throwing `The Bluemix application  Test  was not found`. I have already copied war file in usr/projects folder.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you skipped step 3: Using the configuration files. If you choose to run the scripts interactively, you can skip the configuration but it is strongly suggested to at least read and understand the arguments you will need to provide (in the prepareserverdbs.properties collapse you can find instructions how to create a database service).

In order to create a database service and bind it to a Bluemix application, go to the Bluemix Dashboard, create a new Cloud Foundry application and follow the instructions:

1. Choose "web".
2. Choose the Liberty for Java option.
3. Name your app.
   **Note:** Choose a unique name.
4. Click on the "view app overview" button.
5. In the overview page click on the "add a service or API" button.
6. Choose a DB service type (sqldb, cloudantNoSQLDB) from the Data and Analytics services section.
7. Name the service and click on the "create" button

Comment: thnx for your help. Now moving ahead how to add my project war file? can you please tell me.

Comment: i have completed all the process i can able to see container get created but can not able to view worklight console. all process completed successfully. what is the problem can you help me.

Comment: @Suhas, your best bet is to ask a new question about viewing the console. Since your first question has already been answered, people may not notice that you have asked a new question in your comments.